# Jquery form submit button (chrome issue)

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I'm trying to prevent a form from being submitted twice. I'm doing that by catching clicks on a submit button and disabling it while the form submit goes on in the background.

Here's a very basic example of the code I'm using:

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $(this).attr("disabled","true").html("Wait here while posted...");
});
```

Working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/t93Vw/

This works perfectly in firefox and IE, but in chrome the form is not submitted.
Why is this different behaviour, and does anyone have a quick fix?

Comment: It's not submitting in Chrome for me.

Comment: Tested on chrome 33, latest version and its working (the jsfiddle e.g.)

Comment: @ronish Do you mean it's submitting the FORM, it shouldn't on chrome33

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to submit a form then you should use `onsubmit` event:

```
$("form").submit(function () {
    $(':submit', this).prop("disabled", true).html("Wait here while posted...");
});
```

`onclick` is for click, form has a special event for submission. Advantage is that it will properly behave on Enter key submit.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/t93Vw/1/

Comment: Yes but to who it may help, on submitting the form, value of fields can not be modified .. in this case it is useful to handle the submit behaviour for instance inside the submit button click handler

Comment: Thanks, yes this is the neatest solution i think, "the other way around" way of doing it. Cheers!

Still, it doesnt explain why chrome was handling it differently to the other browsers though.

Comment: @Rob I assume that Chrome disables button "too" fast. And the form is not submitted on disabled button click. So the click event happens before submit form event.

Answer (score 2):

Try [.prop( propertyName, value )](http://api.jquery.com/prop/#prop-propertyName-value) and don't wrap `true` in quotes

> *value* Type: String or Number or Boolean A value to set for the property.

```
$("button").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); //stop default behavior of form submit
    $(this).prop("disabled", true) // disable button
        .text("Wait here while posted...") //change text of button 
        .closest('form').submit();//find closest form and submit it
});
```

[.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

[event.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)

---

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/33uS9/)</kbd>

Comment: that won't submit the FORM on chrome

Answer (score 1):

The type of the button may be the reason ... try this

```
<form action="/test" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="somefield"/>
    <button id="submitbutton">Send</button>
</form>


$("button").click(function(){
    $(this).prop("disabled",true).html("Wait here while posted...")
       .parent().get(0).submit();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: A `<button />` without a `type` will be by default of type `submit` - [HTML/Elements/button](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/button#HTML_Attributes)

Comment: Yep, my sentence is confusing .. the idea is to make sure to prevent de default browser behaviour by executing e.preventDefault(); (by the way I stripped the type attribute since it's useless here)

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what's the error but maybe this will help?

```
$("button").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).attr("disabled","true").html("Wait here while posted...");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For it to work on chrome, do the following updates in your codes:

(1) your form

```
<form action="/test" method="post" id="myForm">
  <input type="text" name="somefield"/>
  <button id="submitbutton" type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

(2) Use jquery to submit the form:

```
$("button").click(function(){ 
  $('form#myForm').submit();
  $(this).attr("disabled","true").html("Wait here while posted...");
});
```